# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener') at Multiselect.componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, multi-select, removeeventlistener

I am currently using `multiselect-react-dropdown` version 2.0.22 and `react` version 18.0.0.
I integrated a multi-select dropdown in one of the forms and when I try to leave the page where the multi-select component is integrated:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener') at Multiselect.componentWillUnmount"
```

Error pops up on the console and the screen goes blank.

This is the multi-select code.

```
const onSelectParticulars = (selectedList: any, selectedItem: any) => {
  setSelectedParticulars([...selectedParticulars, selectedItem]);
};

const onRemoveParticulars = (selectedList: any, removedItem: any) => {
  setRemovedParticulars([...removedParticulars, removedItem]);
};    

<Multiselect
  options={options}
  name="particulars"
  onSelect={onSelectParticulars}
  onRemove={onRemoveParticulars}
  displayValue="name"
  closeIcon="cancel"
  placeholder="Select Particulars"
  selectedValues={particulars}
  className="multiSelectContainer"
/>
```

[I have attached the image of the error obtained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivSFu.png)

Update: This is the full error obtained.

```
react-dom.development.js:12058 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')
    at Multiselect.componentWillUnmount (multiselect-react-dropdown.cjs.development.js:307:1)
    at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (react-dom.development.js:22516:1)
    at safelyCallComponentWillUnmount (react-dom.development.js:22538:1)
    at commitUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23375:1)
    at commitNestedUnmounts (react-dom.development.js:23419:1)
    at unmountHostComponents (react-dom.development.js:23739:1)
    at commitDeletion (react-dom.development.js:23802:1)
    at commitMutationEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24008:1)
    at commitMutationEffects (react-dom.development.js:23992:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26441:1)
```

Comment: This appears to be an issue in the `Multiselect` component. Have you searched the repo for any reported issues, or if there aren't any, reported the issue there with a reproducible example?

Comment: @DrewReese, I searched the repo for a similar issue to be reported, but I didn't find any. I will report this issue to the repo at this moment.

Comment: Can you update your post here with the full error and stacktrace? We may be able to scour the sourcecode and see what/where/why an object is unexpectedly null when trying to remove an event listener.

Comment: It looks to be [this line](https://github.com/srigar/multiselect-react-dropdown/blob/v2.0.21/src/multiselect/multiselect.component.tsx#L159), but oddly enough, it's a React ref that is set in `componentDidMount`, and I don't see anything else in the `Multiselect` component that mutates this ref during the life of the component. Are you sure of the installed version in your app? Run `npm list multiselect-react-dropdown` from your project's root directory and report back the installed version, just to confirm.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I checked it again by typing the command you gave me, and it is version multiselect-react-dropdown@2.0.22

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking. It looks to be the same exact [code](https://github.com/srigar/multiselect-react-dropdown/blob/v2.0.22/src/multiselect/multiselect.component.tsx#L159) down to the line number. This certainly seems like a bug on their part. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese I created the sandbox demo, but I couldn't generate the same issue on the code sandbox. However, the issue still exists in my program.
Here is the demo app I did on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-react-dropdown-mep1xy